# How to create an xOR Protractor ExpectedCondition typescript to wait for element to pass if not equal

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, webautomation

i would like to create an expected condition that if both text are similar it would fail, and if both text are not similar it would pass. Similar to an xOR logic. I got my code below but it has errors, it would be greatly appreciated if you can help me with this. Thanks

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

[image]
[image]

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const TextInfo1 = element(by.id('Text1'));
const TextInfo2 = element(by.id('Text2'));
console.log('Text1:', await TextInfo1.getText());
console.log('Text2:', await TextInfo2.getText());
await browser.wait(EC.or(EC.and(TextInfo1, EC.not(TextInfo2)),EC.and(EC.not(TextInfo1), TextInfo2)), 15000);
```

i got this error on the TextInfo1 and TextInfo2 on the last line of my code.

```
Argument of type 'ElementFinder' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'Function'.
  Type 'ElementFinder' is missing the following properties from type 
'Function': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `ExpectedCondition` can't resolve your problem. A more straight way is to define a function as condition for `browser.wait()` as following:

```
const TextInfo1 = element(by.id('Text1'));
const TextInfo2 = element(by.id('Text2'));

await browser.wait(async function(){
    txt1 = await TextInfo1.getText();
    txt2 = await TextInfo1.getText();
    return txt1 !== txt2;
}, 15000)
```

**Note**: Don't call `getText()` outside `wait()` if you use `await`, we want the `wait()` to fetch the text of both for many times at intervals within the timeout `15 seconds` .

Comment: i'm getting an error on the `txt1` and `txt2` line.. error are:
`Cannot find name 'txt1'.ts(2304)` and `Cannot find name 'txt2'.ts(2304)` .
and also the `=` also has an error. It says:
`';' expected.ts(1005)`

Comment: I made a mistake to put `await` at wrong place. Code updated